# how to use zxing library in windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, zxing

I want to scan products barcode using zxing libray in my Windows phone application .

I'm worndering how to integrate it into the project and how to use it .

thank's in advance .

Answer (score 2):

There is a silverlight port of zxing here that works on WP7: [zxing](http://silverlightzxing.codeplex.com/)

Comment: There is an example of barcode recognition in documentation: http://silverlightzxing.codeplex.com/documentation

Answer (score 1):

Just a little addition for everybody that also searches about this topic: Stéphanie Hertrich built a [small sample application](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stephe/archive/2011/11/07/wp7-real-time-video-scan-a-barcode-qr-code-in-your-app-using-zxing-lib.aspx) that uses the zxing library together with the new Mango Camera API. This way you can search the live camera stream for barcodes and stop immediatelly if something was found. This is much more convenient for the user (just tried it for myself).

Her code is not fully tested, but it works well for a demo and finds those barcodes unbelievably fast (its really impressive, it mostly found it just after the autofocus finished).

Comment: How is it compared to Microsoft's own Tag reader? I think the MS Tag app also uses the live camera stream or am I wrong? Haven't got a WP, would test it..

Comment: I would say it compares quite well in terms of performance (time until it finds a tag and decodes it), I was really impressed as I tried it the first time. And it doesnt just find QR codes but all sorts of barcodes (1D product barcodes etc.). Just MS Tags can only be found with Microsofts own tag reader.

Comment: Thanks. I'm a bit confused by the following point you can find in the project's ToDo-list: "Improve scanning accuracy for all barcode types". Isn't the accuracy the same as in the java version?

Comment: @ceran: I cant give you an objective comparison, and I also didnt try the java version yet. However, subjectively it is very fast and accurate for both qr and 1D barcodes that I tried. It held the phone over the barcode and just after the camera focused the barcode (~1 sec) it instantly recognized it. I cant imagine how this could get any faster.

Comment: @ceran: This comment "Improve scanning accuracy for all barcode types" could mean: improve the time the algorithm needs to decide which barcode type this is, if the 'any-barcode-type'-flag is set. It is a tiny bit faster if your app just needs to scan barcodes of a single type, and you set this type in the library accordingly.